# TLS 1.2 em requisições com RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net

Preciso utilizar o TLS 1.2 em uma requisição HTTP com o RestSharp.

Toda vez que faço um POST, informa o erro "A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Não foi possível estabelecer relação de confiança para o canal seguro de SSL/TLS.".

```
private void CriarServicoWebEEnviar(string url, byte[] sig)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
        var client = new RestClient(url);

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/pkcs7-signature");
        request.AddParameter("application/pkcs7-signature", sig, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    }
```

Estou usando Visual Studio 2010 com o .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: tem certeza que está usando TLS 1.2? no seu código não mostra isso, qual a versão do Framework está usando?

Comment: Ricardo, estou usando o framework 4.0. Atualizei a pergunta com mais informações.

Comment: só para confirmar... está com https e batendo com a porta indicada?

Answer (score 2):

Basta adicionar essa linha antes do execute:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =  SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```